# How to draw a smooth scatter plot where the group of points in the graph are replaced by a smooth coloured region and an exponential scale being used?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to draw a scatter plot where in place of the points in the graphs it is replaced with a colored region. And also the scale in both the X and Y axis from 10^(-4)-1 i.e it should go in the way 10^(-4), 10^(-3), 10^{-2}, 10^(-1), and 1 in both the axis. Here is the code that I am using for the scatter plot. Please suggest what modification is to be done to get the desired plot.

```
mee[m1_, β_, α_, c12_, c13_, s12_, s13_, m2_, 
   m3_] := √(m1 c12^2 c13^2 + 
       m2 s12^2 s13^2 Cos[2 α Degree] + 
       m3 s12^2 c13^2 Cos[2 β Degree])^2 + (m2 s12^2 c13^2 Sin[
        2 α Degree] + m3 s13^2 Sin[2 β Degree])^2;
Tab28 = Table[{m1, 
    mee[m1, Random[Real, {-50, 50}], Random[Real, {3, 9}], 
     Random[Real, {0.851, 0.8062}], Random[Real, {0.9896, 0.9876}], 
     Random[Real, {0.5241, 0.5915}], Random[Real, {0.1438, 0.15695}], 
     Random[Real, {0.0491, 0.05109}], 
     Random[Real, {0.0483, 0.0502}]]}, {m1, 0.0001, 1, 0.9 Degree}];
P29 = ListPlot[Tab28, PlotRange -> {0.0001, 1}, 
  FrameLabel -> {m1, Abs[Subscript[m, ee]]}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Thick]
```

Here is the type of plot which I want to get(the pink region on the graph

[image]

But this is the plot I am getting.

[image]

Comment: Your code(startinng with `m3_]...` ) is incomplete, doesn't ran!

Comment: i've corrected it. please see now if it runs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ConvexHullMesh[Tab28]` to construct the region, but not so smooth.

```
ListPlot[Tab28, PlotRange -> {0.0001, 1}, 
 FrameLabel -> {m1, Abs[Subscript[m, ee]]}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Thick, 
 Epilog -> {Opacity[.2], Red, ConvexHullMesh[Tab28]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And how to make the scale in the X and Y axis look like 0, 10^-1, 10^-2 , 10^-3 , 10^-4 , 1?

Comment: On using this command the whole graph  has become pink. It is not working properly.